# How I can return promise(reject) from catch block of async/await method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am calling a callback method from async method and then that async method is been called by another and then another async method.

I tried using new return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
but it does not work.

```
async function getBookDescription(bookid){
    logger.info("Inside getBookDescription");
    if(booked){
            var getBookDocPromise = promisify(MongoModel.getByBookID);
            return await getVaultDocPromise(bookid)
    }else{
            var getDefaultBookPromise = promisify(MongoModel.getDefaultBookConfigs);
            return await getDefaultBookPromise();
    }
}

async function getbookdetails(bookid, credentials){
    logger.info("Inside getbookdetails");
    var errMessage;
    try {
        try{
            var bookdetails = await getBookDescription(bookid);
        }catch (error) {
            logger.info("error"+JSON.stringify(error));
            return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
        }
        if(bookdetails && bookdetails >0){
            logger.info("got the bookdetails");
            return bookdetails;
        }else{
            logger.info("inside error");
            errMessage = {
                "message": bookDetailsNotFound
            }
            logger.error(errMessage.message);
            return errMessage
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return error
        }
}

async function addbooks(req,res){
    logger.info("Inside addbooks()");
    try {
        var result = await getbookdetails(bookId);
        return res.status(result.statusCode).send(result.message);
      } catch (error) {
          logger.info("inside error");
          return res.status(error.statusCode).send(error);
      }
}
```

expected --> in case when got error from getBookDescription it should throw reject and addbooks catch should be called.

Actual-->UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: code argument is required to res.status
    at ServerResponse.status (/Users/mayank/Documents/work/git/cb-credential-service/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:68:11)
    at addCredsToVault (/Users/mayank/Documents/work/git/cb-credential-service/src/app/v2/api/credential-reference-api.js:55:22)
    at 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
(node:25108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 7)
(node:25108) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I don't think you want `return error` in the other `catch` clause

Comment: What makes you think that "*addbooks catch isn't called.*"? The error quite likely seems to stem from the `response.status(error.statusCode)` call in there, where the `new Error` you rejected with doesn't have a `.statusCode` property.